# PrintAssembly option on JVM Hotspot is enabled but not showing any assembly trace

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am working on intel i386, Ubuntu 14. The OpenJDK version info shown by `$java -version` is

```
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.2) (7u65-2.5.2-3~14.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

As mentioned [here](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/PrintAssembly) I have copied the required binary `hsdis-i386.so` to the following locations

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/server
```

and

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/lib/i386/client
```

Then I followed [this](http://dolzhenko.blogspot.in/2010/04/java-printassembly.html) blog to workaround and try to get an assembly code of a java program. I used below command to test a sample java program `MyClass.java`

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=hsdis-print-bytes -XX:CompileCommand=print,MyClass MyClass
```

The message I got on the console is

```
OpenJDK Server VM warning: PrintAssembly is enabled; turning on DebugNonSafepoints to gain additional output
CompilerOracle: unrecognized line "print Test"
c = 50
```

Where `MyClass.java` is

```
public class MyClass{
  public static void main(String [] args){
    int a = 10;
    int b = 40;
    int c = a + b;
    System.out.println("c = "+c);
  }
}
```

As per my understanding and looking at above message, jvm is able to locate `hsdis-i386.so` and so its saying `PrintAssembly is enabled`, however it is not showing any assembly code out there. Please help me point out the mistake I am doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the JVM, hot methods are compiled after they have been run many times.  e.g. with a `-XX:CompileThreshold=10000` which is the default, a method will be compiled to native code in the background some time after it has been called 10000 times.

Your code is not run enough to get compiled.  I suggest you use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` to see which methods are being compiled.

When I run the following, the output is

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

but when I add `-XX:+PrintCompliation` I see the one method which gets compiled.

```
$ java -XX:+PrintCompilation -version
java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b17)
     43    1       3       java.lang.String::equals (81 bytes)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Well, what should be the command for that? Could you please elaborate a little?

Comment: I mean, how should I use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` option?

Comment: @user1612078 on the command line like the other JVM options you mention.

Comment: I tried this `java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintCompilation -XX:PrintAssemblyOptions=hsdis-print-bytes -XX:CompileCommand=print,MyClass MyClass`, but its not showing any different.

Comment: @user1612078 it is different, try `java -XX:+PrintCompilation -version`  even for a trivial command the output is different.

Comment: What should it show if I use `-XX:+PrintCompilation` option? Because I tried it to run trivial command also but I don't know, its still not showing any different.

Comment: @user1612078 I have added an example of when it is different.

Comment: Well, thanks, though its not showing any different for this command, but yeah it does show if I run a program with some big loop having more than 10000 iterations.

Comment: Let me ask one more question, how can I change the `CompileThreshold`, to make it work for small program like the one I posted ?

Comment: @user1612078 you can set it to a lower number, you could try `=1` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for this problem,
Simply, provide the some delay in your java program by using the for your loop, example:

```
for (int counter=0; 100000 > counter; ++counter); // null statement
```

Then, JVM will use the JIT method and we will get the assembly code.